# Why does the modulo formula to determine what are not prime numbers work for the prime number 2?

Tags: ruby, primes

```
def prime?(num)
  return false if num == 1
  (2..num/2).each do |x|
    if num%x==0
      return false
    end
  end
  true
end
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you can shorten this brute force attempt a bit by going up to the *square root* of `num`, not the half.

Answer (score 2):

Because you never enter your `each`. If the value is 2, then `(2..num/2)` becomes `(2..2/2)`, which is `(2..1)`. Ruby's range operators don't go backwards, so there is nothing to "each" over.

Comment: The good news is that 2 _is_ a prime number so returning `true` is not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since (num/2) is 1 in that case, the loop never runs, so it falls through to the 'true' at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method *is* working:

```
puts prime?(2)
#=> true
```

As someone mentioned in the comments, you can also save some steps by only going through the `sqrt` of the number:

```
(2..Math.sqrt(num)).each do |x|
```